# Issue with Indefinite Execution of Python Subprocess

Tags: python, server, subprocess

I'm encountering an issue with a subprocess in Python. I have a script named v2-local-run.py that I'm running as a subprocess using subprocess.Popen. This script is expected to run for a maximum of 2 minutes. However, sometimes it runs indefinitely, requiring me to manually terminate the process. I start v2-local-run.py with different arguments every minute.

```
import subprocess
import json
import time

flow_name = "my flow name "
arguments = {"key": "value"}

# Run subprocess every minute with different arguments
while True:
    subprocess_triggered = subprocess.Popen(
        ["python", "v2-local-run.py", flow_name, json.dumps(arguments)]
    )
    time.sleep(60)  # Wait for one minute before starting the next subprocess
```

Comment: What's the question? Use `subprocess_triggered.kill()` to kill it.

Comment: But i have to kill this after the process end or if the process not completed after 2 minute then??.. and it should not affect my other code because i'm using async programming

Comment: So start another thread that sleeps for 2 minutes and then does this.